# How to handle OdbcException

Tags: c#, .net

I have this problem that I try to resolve without any success.
I have an input research in which I can make research with keywords. I have a checkBoxList representing different topics (Logistic, Administration, Finance...) to filter the queries. If my keyword is "problem" and I check "Administration" checkbox, the results will only be about "problem" related to Administration. It works fine, but if I dont check any checkbox it leads me to an OdbcException. I tried to handle it with try catch, but it is completely ignored, it is not executed and I still get an error..

Here is my code for the checkboxlist research :

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckboxID" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckboxID_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="ADV"> ADV </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Logistique"> Logistique </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Finance"> Finance </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="EDI"> EDI </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Administration"> Administration </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>

    <label for="tbSearch">Recherche : </label>
     <asp:TextBox ID="tbSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`


protected void Populate()
{
    Occurence = 0;

    string word = tbSearch.Text;

    string strSql = @"SELECT CAST(ID as VarChar(50)) ID, Aggregation, DateDerniereSolution, DateDescription, DerniereSolution, DescriptionDemande, FileDeTraitement, NomContact, Numero, SousRubrique, TitreDemande
    FROM cfao_DigiHelp_index.DigiHelpData WHERE ( 1 = 1 )";

    string selectedValue = "";
    bool IsFirst = false;
    strSql += @" AND (";

    foreach (ListItem item in CheckboxID.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            selectedValue =  item.Value ;
            if (IsFirst)
            {
                strSql += " OR ";
            }
            strSql += " SousRubrique Like '%" + selectedValue + "%' ";
            IsFirst = true; 
        }
    }

    strSql += @"  )";
```

EDIT : 
Got another pb, if I don't check any checkboxes and I enter a word, leads me to that same error, tried everything to make it work I'm going crazy

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't check any checkboxes your condition will be `AND ()` which leads to an exception. Use this:

```
string strSql = @"SELECT CAST(ID as VarChar(50)) ID, Aggregation, DateDerniereSolution, DateDescription, DerniereSolution, DescriptionDemande, FileDeTraitement, NomContact, Numero, SousRubrique, TitreDemande
FROM cfao_DigiHelp_index.DigiHelpData";

if (CheckboxID.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(x => x.Selected))
{
    List<string> conditionList = CheckboxID.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(item => " SousRubrique Like '%" + item.Value + "%' ").ToList();
    strSql += " WHERE (" + string.Join(" OR ", conditionList) + "  )";
}
```

It will concatenate the string only if at least one checkbox is checked.

You need to add `using System.Linq;` on top of your files

Comment: Thx for you answers, I tried your method but tells me that .Any() doesn't exist

Comment: Ok I add using System.Linq but still tells me it doesn't exist :/

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.5

Comment: CheckboxID is the ID of my checkboxlist that I created in the html File

Comment: @Glad it works! Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the best and *bonne chance* ;)

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your code, if `CheckboxID.Item` is empty, you generate the string `...WHERE ( 1 = 1 ) AND (  )`. That doesn't look like a valid syntax to me.

I think you need to handle the `AND (` and the `)` differently - they should only be concatenated if anything is in `CheckboxID.Item`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an invalid syntax error after Where if there is no Items selected or all `if (item.Selected)` evaluates to False, So what you need to Do is Attach the `And` part only if there is any selected item in the `Checkbox`. I would like to check whether any items are selected or not before performing the iteration:

```
if (CheckboxID.Items.Any(x => x.Selected))
{
    strSql +=" AND (";

    foreach (ListItem item in CheckboxID.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            selectedValue =  item.Value ;
            if (IsFirst)
                strSql += " OR ";

            strSql += " SousRubrique Like '%" + selectedValue + "%' ";
            IsFirst = true; 
        }
    }
    strSql += @"  )";
}
```

One more thing, use StringBuilder and avoid `+=` for concatination